# How to convert time in seconds to standard time format in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

How can  convert time in seconds to standard time format in rails.For example 1971 seconds
should be displayed as 0:33:25

Comment: I think that you are wrong in your calculation part. See 1971/60 gives you a value 32.85. It doesn't mean 32 minutes and 85 seconds but it means 32 minutes plus 0.85 minutes which is equal to 51 seconds. That means 1971 seconds will give you 32.51 seconds. Therefore I think that @Ariejan's answer is correct though I have not tested it and I do not guarantee it as perfect solution.

Comment: @user475748 I think you must accept the answer of @Ariejan. I tested it and it is working perfectly as required by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no helper to that for you in rails. But it's quite easy to write your own:

```
def to_dot_time(s)
  h = s / 3600
  s -= h * 3600

  m = s / 60
  s -= m * 60

  [h, m, s].join(":")
end
```

And an example:

```
>> to_dot_time(1971)
=> "0:32:51"
```

Comment: Also not that the 0:33:25 in your question is wrong for 1971 seconds. Or did you use some other means of calculating that value?

Answer (score -1):

While Ariejan's answer is perfectly OK, just for reference I point to another, given on [Ruby-doc Time class docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html) (scroll to the bottom, search for Additional notes). In short, there is a method to convert Numeric to Time instance:

```
Time.at(number)
```

which in turn can be presented using `strftime "%T"`. Caution: as far as I see, it will not show Time instances with more than 23 hours.

Comment: This provides absolute time whereas the questioner asks about relative time.